Can you recommend a good book written about Newton's mathematical achievements?
I'm curious about what exactly Newton achieved in mathematics, but the books I've read about Newton so far only briefly mention his achievements in calculus and focus on his achievements in physics, so I don't know much about his mathematical achievements.
It is very difficult for me to find a book that covers this subject in depth.
Therefore, I would be very grateful if you could recommend a book that excellently describes Newton's mathematical achievements.

I would recommend I.B. Cohen's translation of Newton's Principia. He has about 400 pages of detailed guide for every aspect of the Principia, of course, including mathematics. Extensive references will be helpful to find books about Newton's mathematics. https://www.amazon.com/Principia-Authoritative-Translation-Mathematical-Principles/dp/0520290887

By the way, don’t expect modern style equations or calculus, Newton worked with ratios and proportionalities only.

Adding to Mikhail Katz's  references to the (very good!) books by Niccolo Guicciardini on Newton's mathematics:--
A broad survey of Newton's mathematical interests is given by the 8-volume series of Mathematical Papers of Isaac Newton, edited by D T Whiteside. As far as I know, only the tables of contents are openly available online. But these are  "analytical" tables of contents, as Whiteside called them, and some entries give detailed summary descriptions of the items indexed, so that it can be useful to browse these lists for particular topics of interest.
Also, a number of authors (including Guicciardini) have published papers and reviews of books on Newton's mathematics in the periodical Historia Mathematica, for which there is a useful full list of contents online, and the same is true for Archives for History of Exact Sciences.
These amount to useful searching/browsing tools for finding the existence and location of many of the works that may be of interest about Newton's mathematics and science.
Here are the links:--
Mathematical Papers of Isaac Newton, online Analytical Tables of Contents :
ATOC vol 1:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45957/toc/9780521045957_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 2:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45964/toc/9780521045964_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 3:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45810/toc/9780521045810_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 4:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45834/toc/9780521045834_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 5:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45841/toc/9780521045841_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 6:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45858/toc/9780521045858_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 7:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45896/toc/9780521045896_toc.pdf
ATOC vol 8:  https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/45919/toc/9780521045919_toc.pdf
If any of the links fails, more general pages for the works are HERE for volumes 3-8,
and HERE1 and HERE2 for volumes 1 and 2.
Tables of contents for Historia Mathematica, HERE, are hosted at the Univ of Utah,
and the same goes for tables for Archive for History of Exact Sciences, HERE,.

One of the main authorities on Newton today is Guicciardini.  He has three books on Newton (and numerous articles):

Guicciardini, Niccolò.  Reading the Principia. The debate on Newton's
mathematical methods for natural philosophy from 1687 to 1736. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1999. vi+285 pp. ISBN:
0-521-64066-0


Guicciardini, Niccolò.  The development of Newtonian calculus in
Britain 1700–1800. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1989. xii+228 pp. ISBN: 0-521-36466-3


Guicciardini, Niccolò.  Isaac Newton on mathematical certainty and
method. Transformations: Studies in the History of Science and
Technology. MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, 2009. xxviii+422 pp. ISBN: 978-0-262-01317-8

If you clarify which particular aspect of Newton's mathematics you are interested in, I can try to look up what Guicciardini may have said about it.

Thanks for mentioning Guicciardini's book, https://is.muni.cz/www/jannovotny/newton/Reading-the-Principia-The-Debate-on-Newton-s-Mathematical-Methods-for-Natural-Philosophy-from-1687-to-1736.pdf?lang=en

There is an article by Derek Whiteside,
Newton the mathematician,
published in the book "Contemporary Newtonian research",
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-7715-0_3
Also there exists an edition "Newton's Mathematical papers" in several languages, with commentaries. The authors of commentaries are different in all languages, English edition was commented by the same Whiteside.
There is also a little book by Arnold, Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke, which highlights some (but not all) of his mathematical achievements.

In the first volume of the Baroque Cycle trilogy -- a historical fiction -- Isaac Newton is one of the characters (along with Leibniz and others) described with some detail.
The author was an English -- rather than a Math -- major, which makes it a great read for general public, even if lacking some details a Mathematician might appreciate.
